# What class is necessary to import for the use of the "saveToFile" method in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

I saw a programming example online that utilizes this method and did not know if it was user defined or if there was a default class that contained it. The website did not state this.

Comment: Could you maybe give a link to the programming example?

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml

Comment: It doesn't appear to the a standard method, it is likely to be library specific.

Comment: I apologize for not seeing it in the example. Sorry for the useless question. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the article you link to. See the section titled
"Saving the public and private key"

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml

Answer (score 1):

> In our example,

The web site gives you the code for this method. It explains this is an example of how it could be done.